# Android OpenGL.ES Canvas Position Location

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

You have purposely placed every background image, sprite, button, and TouchEvent coordinate on the screen, but my question is this:

Once placed on the screen, is there a native method that 'sees' what coordinate (x, y, z) the object/image/triangle is located without having to manually put the location?

I could make a helper class that holds the x,y,z coordinate  of the triangle that is located on the Canvas, injecting it as soon as I place the object onto the screen.

But I was wondering if there is a method I can use that obtains the position of the object, making things quicker and smoother.

This goes for these 'languages':

Native Android SDK/API.
OpenGL ES 1
OpenGL ES 2

Comment: AFAIK all dimension handling (including location dimensions) have to be handled by you. Your helper class may be the way to go, if there is a method for handling this better I would like to know myself.

Comment: AFAIK='As far as I know', sorry acronyms bother me. Yeah I wanted to be able to have the boundaries of the object, other than just the Triangle coordinates, bounder layer(For collision-check purposes), but I would like to call a method that tells me where exactly it is on the screen. I will end up having a big canvas (goes past the Phone's Screen) and it'll be nice to know where on that a specific object is. Helps in Game Development. I'll post my remedy code later on once I start working on it!